# Rewriting $\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h$ into $\frac{h(h+1)-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with how to rearrange the equation $\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h$. In the solutions booklet the answer to this question is $$\frac{h(h+1)-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}$$ however I got $$\frac{h(h+1)-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h}$$ instead (difference is the +/- sign.)

Here's how I did it:
$$\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h$$ = $$(h(h+1))^{1/2})^2-h^2$$ = $$(\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h)(\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h)$$ = ${h(h+1)-h^2}$. At this point I divided ${h(h+1)-h^2}$ by the original equation because I raised it to a power 2. So I did

$$\frac{h(h+1)-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h}$$

This solution doesn't fit the one in the textbook. I'm not sure where to get the $\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h$ in the denominator.

Comment: Multiply the expression by $\dfrac{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}$ and use $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ in numerator.

Comment: The mistake is that you started by writing $\sqrt {h(h+1)} - h = (h(h+1)^{(1/2)})^2 - h^2$ which is wrong. It would be like saying $a - b = a^2 - b^2$ which it is completely not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **rationalize**, specifically as follows:
$$\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h=\left(\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h\right)\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}}$$
**Note:** I have multiplied and divided by $\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h$, in fact the idea is to eliminate the square root, using the equality: $\color{green}{(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2}$

So now we have:
$$\left(\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h\right)\frac{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}=\frac{h(h+1)-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}$$
where to obtain the numerator I have used the equality in green.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt a -\sqrt b=\frac {(\sqrt a -\sqrt b) (\sqrt a +\sqrt b)} {\sqrt a +\sqrt b}=\frac {a-b} {(\sqrt a +\sqrt b)} $.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h=\frac{\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h}1=\frac{(\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h)(\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h)}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}==\frac{\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}$$

Answer (score 0):

If you notice carefully, we have a difference of a square root our variable. We can multiply by its conjugate (that's changing the sign between the terms) and simplify by difference of squares.

$$\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h=(\sqrt{h(h+1)}-h)\frac{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}+h} = \frac{h(h+1)-h^2}{\sqrt{h(h+1)}}$$

which is the answer in the textbook you are wondering about.